# How to firebase.login() & createNewUser() with react-redux-firebase and email link firebase passwordless auth?

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-redux-firebase

I’m working on a react native application that uses [Firebase Email Link (passwordless) Auth]((https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth)
I have created a ‘users’ collection on the Firestore database.
In order to easily sync users profile data to the redux store,I decided to use [react-redux-firebase](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/getting_started)

I have already configured the `rrfConfig` and followed every single steps as stated in the getting started documentation, but still remain some parts that unclear and not documented. It’ll be great to get someone’s help on any ideas on how to tackle this part:

1) How to log in users with `firebase.login({params})` that are signed up with [email link (passwordless)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) using the methods outlined in the [auth section](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/auth.html#examples)?

This the email/password example:

```js
firebase.login({
  email: 'test@test.com',
  password: 'testest1'
})
```

Since the user does not have a password, or credential or accessToken after he signed up using email link `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink(email, window.location.href)` all we have is a `uid` and `email`:

```js
firebase.login({
  email: 'test@test.com',
  // any ideas to add here?
})
```

2) Similarly, how to create users with [createUser(credentials, profile)](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/auth.html#createusercredentials-profile) using [email link (passwordless)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth
) auth?

```js
const createNewUser = ({ email, password, username }) => {
  firebase.createUser( // should password be replaced by url?
    { email, password },
    { username, email }
  )
}
```

Thank you in advance for helping out with any ideas on how to tackle this

Comment: There is no answer anywhere. I might have to drop email link authentication feature and implement old fashion email and password authentication.